# XCode 4.3 Unable to load persistent store UserDictionary.sqlite

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, store, persistent

I have been working on an iOS app for some time, all of a sudden I am getting the following crash every time I run the app in the iOS 5.1 Simulator.

The App does not use Core Data and I am not sure what brought this about.

I have deleted the app from the simulator, done Clean, and a rebuild but nothing seems to help.

```
Unable to load persistent store at URL 'file://localhost/Users/jcottrell/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Library/Keyboard/UserDictionary.sqlite' ({
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 407;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            UserDictionaryEntry = <f0c9025b 602122f9 37a4e274 bdaacec1 b9a66f83 fca5c43b bed5e80a 6baee338>;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "43DABF34-7F7E-4FE9-B78D-8AF64292A967";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
})
```

Comment: Did you install a later version of Xcode (4.4 / 4.5)? I did, the same problem happened to me.

Comment: Yes, I think that's where it came from!

Comment: I've been having this same issue in 4.5 Preview. :(

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. I clicked 'iOS Simulator' -> Reset Content and Settings

Comment: I just install xcode 4.5 yesterday, not the prerelease, and still have the same problem. Thanks JonathanC, reset my simulator works.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the file you mentioned: `/Users/jcottrell/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Library/Keyboard/UserDictionary.sqlite` and the accompanying `plist`. This is a simulator-only problem, so you can ignore it.