# App crashes in simulator when ever keyboard is presented

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, uikeyboard, xcode4.4

I have an app that I have been working with for over a year, it has been working fine. All of a sudden it has started crashing in the simulator when ever a keyboard is presented. It doesn't matter where the keyboard is presented from. The app still works on my device.

I am using Xcode 4.4 and iOS 5.1. I did install Xcode 4.5 a few days ago in a separate directory, perhaps this is what caused the problem.

Here is the error that I'm getting on the console, does anyone have a solution?

```
Unable to load persistent store at URL 'file://localhost/Users/myusername/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Library/Keyboard/UserDictionary.sqlite' ({
metadata =     {
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
        UserDictionaryEntry = <f0c9025b 602122f9 37a4e274 bdaacec1 b9a66f83 fca5c43b bed5e80a 6baee338>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "9CF44513-5DA9-4BB7-B88E-9C705D1874A5";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
};
reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
})
2012-09-14 19:10:05.988 MyAppName[62761:4d13] Unable to load persistent store at URL     'file://localhost/Users/myusername/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Library/Keyboard/UserDictionary.sqlite' ({
metadata =     {
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
        UserDictionaryEntry = <f0c9025b 602122f9 37a4e274 bdaacec1 b9a66f83 fca5c43b bed5e80a 6baee338>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "9CF44513-5DA9-4BB7-B88E-9C705D1874A5";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
};
reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
})
2012-09-14 19:10:05.990 MyAppName[62761:4d13] Unable to load persistent store at URL 'file://localhost/Users/myusername/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Library/Keyboard/UserDictionary.sqlite' ({
metadata =     {
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
        UserDictionaryEntry = <f0c9025b 602122f9 37a4e274 bdaacec1 b9a66f83 fca5c43b bed5e80a 6baee338>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "9CF44513-5DA9-4BB7-B88E-9C705D1874A5";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
};
reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here:

[XCode 4.3 Unable to load persistent store UserDictionary.sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11040681/472344)

I just had to reset the Simulator. The issue was likely caused by installing Xcode 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me. You can also fixed this problem by selecting and clicking 'iOS Simulator' -> Reset Content and Settings.